# Is there way to optimize the speed for changing values in a >2 million row data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

I have got a `tibble` of more than 2 million rows. One of the columns `size` is a value using M to represent million, k to represent thousand; it also has some `<NA>` values. The column type is `character`, like the following:

```r
size
1.3M
5k
302
8.6M
<NA>
4.4k
21
```

...and so on.

I tried the following code:

```r
for (i in 1:length(example$size)) {
  if (!is.na(example$size[i])) {
    if (str_sub(example$size[i],-1,-1) == "M") {
      example$size[i] = as.numeric(str_sub(example$size[i], 1,-2)) * 1000000
    } else if (str_sub(example$size[i],-1,-1) == "k") {
      example$size[i] = as.numeric(str_sub(example$size[i], 1,-2)) * 1000
    }
  }
}
```

But it took more than half hour and still running, so I interrupted that as I was not sure if my code was wrong and it's in a infinite loop. Is there anything wrong or any way of coding to improve the efficiency?

Comment: Don't use a loop, use vectorized operations.  You'll need to use regular expressions to match the different patterns, then apply them to the whole column at once.  It will be at least 100 times faster, maybe more.

Comment: If you want code, post a reproducible example.  It doesn't need to contain 2 million rows, just a sample of the types of entries that are present in the column.

Comment: https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could accomplish everything using `str_replace_all` and `as.numeric`:

```
 as.numeric(stringr::str_replace_all(size, c(M = "e6", k = "e3")))
 [1] 1300000    5000      NA      21    4400
```

Edit:

A faster approach is to use baseR `sub` function twice:

```
as.numeric(sub("k", "e3", sub("M", "e6", bigsize,fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE))
```

A quick microbenchmark check shows that this method is the fastest:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
   a = as.numeric(sub("k", "e3", sub("M", "e6", bigsize,fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)),
   b = as.numeric(str_replace_all(bigsize, c(M = "e6", k = "e3"))),
   rep1 = rep1(bigsize),
   rep2 = rep2(bigsize), 
   rep3 = rep3(bigsize),
   rep4 = rep4(bigsize),
   rep5 = rep5(bigsize_df), times=3)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
    a   621.1582   638.9055   664.4689   656.6529   686.1242   715.5955     3
    b  1102.8758  1108.1215  1118.1558  1113.3673  1125.7958  1138.2244     3
 rep1  1450.3998  1478.7379  1547.1752  1507.0761  1595.5629  1684.0497     3
 rep2  6144.4160  6419.0407  8411.8940  6693.6654  9545.6329 12397.6005     3
 rep3 19224.9825 19225.2984 19427.0457 19225.6143 19528.0773 19830.5402     3
 rep4  1188.0552  1310.4584  1368.6480  1432.8616  1458.9444  1485.0273     3
 rep5  3056.1525  3177.7098  3672.9781  3299.2671  3981.3909  4663.5148     3
```

Answer (score 3):

I get about 3 seconds for 2M rows on this, which sounds like a ~600x improvement.

```
# example data
size <- c("1.3M","5k",NA,21,"4.4k")
bigsize <- c(replicate(4e5, size))  # big(ish) example for benchmarking
bigsize_df <- data.frame(bigsize) # 2,000,000 rows


# split out k/M
library(dplyr)
rep5 <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    mutate(num = readr::parse_number(bigsize),
           suffix = stringr::str_match_all(bigsize, "k|M"),
           num2 = num * case_when(suffix == "M" ~ 1E6,
                                  suffix == "k" ~ 1E3,
                                  TRUE ~ 1))
}

#3.003 sec 
tictoc::tic()
rep5(bigsize_df)
tictoc::toc()
```

Result:

```
  bigsize  num suffix    num2
1    1.3M  1.3      M 1300000
2      5k  5.0      k    5000
3    <NA>   NA     NA      NA
4      21 21.0             21
5    4.4k  4.4      k    4400
6    1.3M  1.3      M 1300000
etc.
```

Comment: Huh. Mildly surprising that this is so much faster than my solutions ...

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised too so I'd be curious if someone can figure it out.

Comment: In any case, "more than half an hour" to "3 seconds" is a pretty good improvement :-)

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring, just tried it and took only 2~3 seconds! Simply amazing, I appreciate your help. I need to learn much more on the concept of vectorization.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** vectorizing speeds things up by a factor of 5, trying to be clever about avoiding replicate processing gets a 30-fold speed gain. Still takes about 1.5 seconds for a vector of length 50,000 (so expecting about 1 minute for 2 million entries ...)

- both the original method and @KacZdr's suggestion produce character vectors, because replacing values within a character vector by numeric values coerces them back to character (you could always use `as.numeric()` at the end); @KacZdr's solution gives warnings.

```r
size <- c("1.3M","5k",NA,21,"4.4k")
bigsize <- c(replicate(1e4, size))  # big(ish) example for benchmarking

## process outside of function to avoid repetition

prefixes <- c("M"=1e6, "k"=1e3)
re <- sprintf("[%s]", paste(names(prefixes), collapse =""))

rep1 <- function(size) {
    rx <- regexpr(re, size)         ## find matches
    w <- which(!is.na(rx) & rx > 0) ## indices for replacement
    sw <- size[w]
    vals <- prefixes[substr(sw, rx[w], rx[w])]      ## find letter values
    result <- numeric(length(size))                 ## allocate result vector
    result[-w] <- as.numeric(size[-w])              ## assign non-suffixed values
    result[w] <- as.numeric(sub(re, "", sw))*vals   ## assign suffixed values
    result
}
```

Wrap the other two approaches in functions for benchmarking:

```r
rep2 <- function(size) {
    size <- ifelse(!is.na(size) & grepl("M",size),as.numeric(sub("M.*", "", size))*1000000,size)
    size <- ifelse(!is.na(size) & grepl("k",size),as.numeric(sub("k.*", "", size))*1000,size)
    return(size)
}
```

Original:

```r
library(stringr)
rep3 <- function(size) {
    for (i in 1:length(size)) {
        if (!is.na(size[i])) {
            if (str_sub(size[i],-1,-1) == "M") {
                size[i] = as.numeric(str_sub(size[i], 1,-2)) * 1000000
            } else if (str_sub(size[i],-1,-1) == "k") {
                size[i] = as.numeric(str_sub(size[i], 1,-2)) * 1000
            }
        }
    }
    size
}
```

```r
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(rep1(bigsize), rep2(bigsize), rep3(bigsize))[,1:5]
```

```
           test replications elapsed relative user.self
1 rep1(bigsize)          100   1.451    1.000     1.452
2 rep2(bigsize)          100   7.812    5.384     7.807
3 rep3(bigsize)          100  41.489   28.593    41.485
```

---

Here's another idea, that I thought would be faster than `rep1()` but isn't really:

```r
rep4 <- function(size) {
    lastchar <- stringr::str_sub(size, -1, -1)
    w <- grep(re, lastchar)
    sw <- size[w]
    vals <- prefixes[lastchar[w]]      ## find letter values
    result <- numeric(length(size))                 ## allocate result vector
    result[-w] <- as.numeric(size[-w])              ## assign non-suffixed values
    result[w] <- as.numeric(sub(re, "", sw))*vals   ## assign suffixed values
    result
}
```

Comment: I wonder if these scale up better than you're projecting, or if faster for some reason in a data frame, or what else would explain why the code I'm running in my answer seems to work and be faster than you're expecting. It doesn't seem like it should be faster...

Comment: I'm curious too.  But probably won't spend any more time on this one ...

Comment: The one liner function below should be faster than the methods presented here

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker The explanation is really in detailed! Thanks for the comprarision, it helps a lot on understanding the different in efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
size <- c("1.3M","5k",NA,21,"4.4k")

size <- ifelse(!is.na(size) & grepl("M",size),as.numeric(sub("M.*", "", size))*1000000,size)
size <- ifelse(!is.na(size) & grepl("k",size),as.numeric(sub("k.*", "", size))*1000,size)
```

**EDIT (to avoid errors):**

```
size <- ifelse(!is.na(size) & grepl("M",size),suppressWarnings(as.numeric(sub("M.*", "", size)))*1000000,size)
size <- ifelse(!is.na(size) & grepl("k",size),suppressWarnings(as.numeric(sub("k.*", "", size)))*1000,size)
```

output:

```
> size
[1] "1300000" "5000"    NA        "21"      "4400"
```

Comment: this is nice. It *might* be possible to further optimize the lookup, but nothing obvious springs to mind